# Custom Authorize Attribute not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

In my c# app I am adding a custom attribute like this

```
public class CheckLogIn : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;
        return (Auth.UserLoggedIn || Auth.AdminLoggedIn);
    }
}
```

I am calling this attribute like this

```
[CheckLogIn]
public dynamic Create(String projectName, String organizationId)
{
    Project pro = Project.Create(organizationId, projectName).Save();

    return new
    {
        organizationId = pro.OrganizationId,
        name = pro.Name,
        id = pro.Id
    };
}
```

The AuthorizeCore is not being called. I have a break point there but it seems like it never gets called. Am I missing something here?

**I have tried calling [CheckLogIn] from a regular controller it works, from an api controller it doesn't.**

Comment: Did you register it on application start?

Comment: No but I have tried calling [CheckLogIn] from a regular controller it works, from an api controller it doesn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [**`System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for WebApi is a different type than the [**`System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for MVC.

The reason why it doesn't work with WebApi is because WebApi doesn't know about MVC types. You need to create a type that inherits **`System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`** for that purpose.